# multi-line text view in table layout. I want to show multi-line text in textView at run time. the textView is inside table layout (tablerow)

Tags: android, xml

I want to show multi-line text in textView at run time. the textView is inside table layout (tablerow).

this is my simple layout code. the second text view id link_name contain text more than a line and it populate from server at run time the text goes off the screen. I tried sherinkColoum="0" but still not works. sorry for my bad English. thanks in advance.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    >
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link"
            android:layout_below="@id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Link"
        />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/link_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/link"
            android:layout_below="@id/image_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="Link"

        />
  </TableLayout>
```

Comment: add android:input="textMultiLine" to your TextView and will expand depending upon the texts entered. If you want to force the number of lines use android:minLines/ android:maxLines. Just in case things dont show up then try setting android:singleLine="false". :)

Comment: thanks for replay. but i use it and still not work. the text divides into two lines but some text at corner disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

change that 2nd textView (id="@+id/link_name") as EditText. then follow the below code

```
EditText link_name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.link_name);
link_name.setSingleLine(false);
link_name.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it too and failed.

The left row has the same size for me, so I am using a linear layout:

```
vertical
  horizontal
    left row
    right row
  horizontal
    left row
    right row
  horizontal
    left row
    right row
  horizontal
    left row
    right row
```

This is my layout file:

```
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:text="@string/mundraub_rule_1"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:maxLines="100"
                android:text="@string/mundraub_rule_2"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:maxLines="100"
                android:text="@string/mundraub_rule_3"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:maxLines="100"
                android:text="@string/mundraub_rule_4"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```